# How to update balance of imported address in electrum

Tags: address, bitcoin-core, balance, electrum

Imported an address into electrum, but the balance of the address shows up as zero.

Checked the address on [http://blockexplorer.com](http://www.bitvisitor.com/) and it's not zero.

The address was imported from bitcoinqt when the blockchain is out of date and the transactions were never attributed to the address.

Nothing was sent from the address.

How would you refresh the transaction history for the imported address in electrum, so it becomes spendable again?

Thanks

**EDIT: The problem has been solved - see workaround below**

A workaround for this is to **send a small amount of bitcoins to the the imported address**

This was done by watching an ad at [www.bitvisitor.com](http://www.bitvisitor.com/).

Once payment was confirmed in the blockchain, Electrum refreshed the balance and the transaction history.

The imported address balance is now spendable :)

Answer (score 1):

You could try with other server, maybe the one you were using was lagging in the moment you imported the address.

To switch servers just go to the green ball at the bottom-right Network and select other server.